# Flutter not showing intelli suggestion box for colors pallet in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am going through one video tutorial on Flutter. When the author types "Color.blueGray" it shows her a list of blue gray color pallet in the suggestion box. But when I try to do similar it doesn't show me that box.

I tried a restart of android studio. I tried various hotkeys and settings but its not working.

This is how it should look

[image]

But on my system it looks like this[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The window you are missing is the quick documentation window.
You can activate it in `settings/Editor/General/Other/Show quick documenation on mouse move`

Comment: You are the Man! Thank you so much Markus

Comment: I found the option and enabled it, but this hasn't changed anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try hitting `Ctrl + Q` to get the quick documentation.